# Conditional object types when value changes

Tags: typescript

Sorry about the question title, I am not quite sure how to phrase it.

I am fairly new to Typescript and wanted to add strong types to a new project.

Lets say I have a function that accepts two parameters: `value` and `params` written like

```
type Value = 'category' | 'follows' | 'users'; 

request(value: Value, params: object)
```

As you can see `Value` type only accepts *three* predefined values. But `params` should be conditionally typed when `value` changes:

If value is `category`, then params should type as `{ author: string, year: number }`, if it is `users` then it should type `{ id: number }` OR `{ name: string }`

And that's the whole challenge of it. I can do it with objects and indexes but have been stuck with types.

Is it even possible to do this ?

Thanks a lot !

NVH

**EDIT**: Thanks a lot for all your help, I had a good time reading all of the documentation as well, since I want to have the safest types for my function I will go for @captain-yossarian solution but the others worked as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works only with TS nightly, see [this PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/46266).

```js
type Value = 'category' | 'follows' | 'users';


type Arguments =
    | ['category', { author: string, year: number },]
    | ['users', { id: number } | { name: string }]
    | ['follows', Record<PropertyKey, unknown>]

const request = (...[value, params]: Arguments) => {
    if (value === 'category') {
        params.author // ok
        params.year
    }


    return 'UNIMPLEMENTED'
}
```

[Playground](http://tsplay.dev/mx69Zw)

See [rest-parameters-with-tuple-types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types) for more explanation about using spread syntax in ts

However, you might have a problems with `users`. See example:

```js
const request = (...[value, params]: Arguments) => {
    if (value === 'category') {
        params.author // ok
        params.year
    }

    if(value==='users'){
        params.id // <------------- error
    }

    return 'UNIMPLEMENTED'
}
```

TypeScript does not allow you to get `params.id`. In fact, TS does not allow you to get any property of `params` if `value` is `users` because union `{ id: number } | { name: string }` does not have common properties. Hence, the safest way is to forbid using any property.

In order to narrow `params` type when `value` is `users` I think it worth using [custom type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```js
type Value = 'category' | 'follows' | 'users';

type UsersId = { id: number }
type UsersName = { name: string }

// TYPE GUARD
const isUserId = (data: UsersId | UsersName): data is UsersId => 'id' in data

// TYPE GUARD
const isUserName = (data: UsersId | UsersName): data is UsersName => 'name' in data

type Arguments =
    | ['category', { author: string, year: number },]
    | ['users', UsersId | UsersName]
    | ['follows', Record<PropertyKey, unknown>]

const request = (...[value, params]: Arguments) => {
    if (value === 'category') {
        params.author // ok
        params.year
    }

    if (value === 'users') {
        if(isUserId(params)){
            params.id // ok
        }
    }

    return 'UNIMPLEMENTED'
}
```

Comment: Oh that's cute :)

Answer (score 3):

There's a lot of ways to do this, but here are two.

---

#### Function overloads [(docs)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#overload-signatures-and-the-implementation-signature)

```
function request(value: 'category', params: { author: string, year: number }): void
function request(value: 'users', params: { id: number } | { name: string }): void
function request(
    value: 'category' | 'users',
    params: { author: string, year: number } | { id: number } | { name: string }
) {
    // TODO: implementation
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAJwKYEcSoM5QBQBuAhgDZYBciA5BEVKgOZzICeVANIgA5HJEC22SgG9EREFAAWzSrmQwwDTi1S9KYEPwBGqZIgC+ASkoE4MACYBYAFChIsBCgxZchUhWohsu7B268BIURRC3VNHT19RAAfYMQwAVRZKHlFA2NEUwsbO2h4JDRMHHwbRDLM9yTqWnomVioYz29kX3ZS8p4+QRExCWlkZNSlRBU1ePDdA0aQ8zDtSajY0QT+KrkFBgMbQ2D2soB6fcQAFQB5ABFTyhh+LhJUVbAoOnybfSA)

---

#### Lookup type with a generic function [(docs)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#generic-functions)

```
type Value = 'category' | 'follows' | 'users'; 
type ObjectLookup = {
    category: { author: string, year: number }
    users: { id: number } | { name: string }
    follows: { foo: string }
}

function request<T extends Value>(value: T, params: ObjectLookup[T]) {
  // TODO: implementation...
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4&ssl=9&ssc=72&pln=3&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK7QLxQOQGM7AgcwHsAnEDKAH0wDNCEFCB3AZ3KoyWYmNYG4oAsAChhoSFADyAIwBWELMAAyhQgGskYKOgDewqPqg48RUgC4o2qHCTAAFiXPNgxAJYA7fABooICHGLmbkgAtlLcUAC+egac3Mzmli4AJoEhYcSRlBZQbnDBEI7O7viR0fq09Ezx2bSEha4epUJRIkLUSG4KLoRuUMQQAI4oTgA8ACpQEAAeeG5JzLCIKAB8ABQAbksFUGPeYP551dJyCspqGgDaYwC6AJQWEUA)

Answer (score 1):

[Function Overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads)

Example:

```
type Value = 'category' | 'follows' | 'users'; 
function request(value: 'category', params: Type1):ResponseType;
function request(value: 'follows', params: Type2):ResponseType;
function request(value: 'users', params: Type3):ResponseType;
function request(value: Value, params: Object):ResponseType{
    ...implementation
}
```

TS is able to see what the type of a prop is and infer what the other props in the respective variant of an overloaded function are.